# Is there any difference between "into" and "to the inside of" in this particular context?

Tags: meaning, usage, idiomatic-language

Is there any difference between "into" and "to the inside of" in this particular context? I understand that "into" and "to the inside of" don't have the same meaning in all contexts, but I was wondering if they did in certain context. I found that "into" and "to" can be used to indicate the destination of the action "migrate", but I am wondering when I can use "into" and if it's synonymous to "to the inside of". If not, how are they different?

For example:

> He migrated into the cave on the hill.
>
> He migrated to the inside of the cave on the hill.

Comment: Why "migrated"?  It can be used to mean "travel" but in a very figurative way.  Otherwise, for people, it suggests changing one's place of residence from one country to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, they may mean similar things in certain contexts, but "into" and "inside" are better examples of synonyms for your example.

> He migrated into the cave.
>   He migrated inside the cave.

These sentences are very close in meaning.

"He migrated to the inside of the cave" could mean he is going to an area of the cave that is considered the inside.